# GCP - should I have multiple egress IP address?

Tags: networking, ip, google-cloud-platform, nat

Our company hosts infra on GCP. Default network is connected to cloud NAT. Because API provider we work with need to whitelist our IP address, I am adding static IP to the cloud NAT.

The question is - should I assign just one IP address or multiple IP addresses?

My understanding of pros/cons:

pros:

- potentially API provider can have rate limit per IP. If we have multiple IPs we have more rate limits

cons:

- it's tedious to whitelist multiple IPs

Both doesn't seem very strong point so I guess it doesn't matter? What is the best practice for egress IP addresses? Should I have one or multiple? If multiple how many is recommended?

Comment: Well if I don't have static IP NAT will auto assign IPs so I can get more than one IPs. Or if I don't have NAT, each VM can have its own IP. So I really don't think having multiple static IP is abuse.

For your second question, per google's documentation there is vm-per-port limit, if VM has more connection than that, VM will obviously get new egress IP.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your cloud implementation, even when you have 65535 available ports for each IP address, GCP Cloud NAT will only use [64512](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/ports-and-addresses#ports) for each protocol, so if your implementation on GCP requires more than those number of ports, then you must add new static IPs, this is automatically solved when using "Auto-Allocation" to scale up or down at any given moment without manual intervention, but this would select any random IP address to use (which might not be white-listed).

I am wild guessing here (since I don't know much about your implementation), but I would use multiple static IPs in order to have some spare ports in case your system out-grow those limits.